# Group multiple simulink Bus Objects into structures

Tags: matlab, simulink

**Short version**

I am considering to use BusObjects to implement hard interface control on a (large industrial) application using Simulink and I would like to store the BusObjects (hundrends of them) into a Matlab structure so that the entire application interface specification is well organized. However, it seems that BusObjects cant be contained into structures, nor they can reside on other workspaces other than Matlab Base. Any idea on how to handle this?

**Long version**

I would like the interfaces specification to be hierarchical and centralized in some way. I mean, I would like to specify the external interface of my application, then the internal interfaces, then the internal interfaces of the internal interfaces and so on. And I would like this information to be stored in one object that resembles the hierarchy. I was thinking in using an structure with BusObjects as elements.

Unfortunately, it seems that, for a bus object to work, it must be declared on the Matlab workspace as an independent variable of class BusObject. It cant be an element of an structure that is a BusObject, or an element of a cell whose elements are BusObjects or an element of a BusObject vector.

Any suggestion on how to handle this? take into account that if you have a model with dozens and dozens of blocks and more than 3 hierarchy levels, then you end up with hundreds of bus objects in the Matlab workspace without any particular structure... I think that is too messy to let it be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bus objects are always stored in the global workspace.

Send a request to Mathworks if you want to change this.